# Is there a way to initialize the starting point of scipy.optimize.linprog?

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a sequence of linear programs to solve. Each instance only differs from the previous one with the A, bounds, and costs being slightly different. Intuitively, the solutions from previous problems should help. How can I go about implementing that?

[scipy.optimize.linprog](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/optimize.linprog-revised_simplex.html#linprog-method-revised-simplex) has an option `x0`

> x0: 1-D array, optional
>
> Starting values of the independent variables, which will be refined by the optimization algorithm. For the revised simplex method, these must correspond with a basic feasible solution.

which appears to do that, but doesn't seem to work if I just initialize the results from the previous optimization (`res.x`). It fails with the following error:

```
6 : Guess x0 cannot be converted to a basic feasible solution
```

Comment: I would not place too much hopes there as A: scipy's implementation is rather limited compared to state-of-the-art commercial solvers (which might offer more *repair-like* functionality) and more important B: the mutations you are doing are, without further assumptions, are killing all nice guarantees. Things where simplex is used in an incremental way are usually cases, where the modifications either lead to *keeping primal feasibility* or *keeping dual feasibility*. In your case, neither is guaranteed. If performance is so important, start using a state-of-the-art solver (not scipy).

Answer (score 1):

The error basically means that `res.x` from the problem you just solved does not satisfy the constraints of the problem you are trying to solve when passing in `res.x` as `x0`.

Why is that? The solution to a linear programming problem is always at one of the vertices of the feasible set, basically on the boundary of what is allowed by your constraints. If you next problem varies a bit from the one you solved, it is highly likely that the solution of the previous problem does not satisfy the constraints of the new one -- it was on the boundary and small changes to the problem moved the boundary a bit and made the previous point be outside. Without knowing the details of your optimization problem it is hard to recommend a sensible strategy here. For example, if you know that the point (0,...,0) is always feasible, you can scale all coordinates of `res.x` down until you get into the feasible set.

It has been a while so I am not sure, but you can try `method='interior-point'` as it may be more forgiving to `x0` being outside the feasible set. Otherwise Google 'how to find a feasible solution for linear programming problem'